# connection issue between godaddy shared hosting and amazon ec2 mongodb

Tags: amazon-ec2, mongodb, shared-hosting

I have a site on godaddy shared hosting that is not able to connect to an windows 2k12 amazon ec2 instance running mongodb.  Any ideas why I cannot connect?  Thanks for your help!

Error message:

```
A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond (my ip):27017

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond (my ip):27017
```

Comment: Is the error message not helpful enough?  What have you tried? Firewall in the way? Is the service listening?

Answer (score 0):

I just heard back from GoDaddy that they intentionally block access to external resources/ip's for their shared hosting accounts.  What crap!  They're intentionally making their product less useful to their customer to try and force them to pay for a more expensive tier of hosting.  If anyone knows of a good shared hosting provider for Windows/.NET that doesn't do stuff like this, I'm all ears!  Thanks!